# проблема с вывода данных из бд по категориям PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Добрый день  друзья возникла проблема с выводом данных из бд по категориям .Никакой  ошибки  при вводе в коде не обнаружил  но  ввод данных  из бд по категориям не осуществляется.Помогите с этим вопросом . Вот код

```
    <?php

    include 'pages/db.php';

    $cars=$_GET['cars'];

    switch($cars){

  case"audi":$cars="SELECT * FROM `car` WHERE car_name=audi";break;
  case"bmw":$cars="SELECT * FROM `car` WHERE car_name=bmw";break;
  case"jaguar":$cars="SELECT * FROM `car` WHERE car_name=jaguar";break;
  case"maserati":$cars="SELECT * FROM `car` WHERE 
  car_name=maserati";break;
  default:$cars="SELECT * FROM `car`";

    }

    ?>

 Вот ссылки 



 <nav class="car_navigation" role="navigation">

<a href="index.php?cars=audi" class="car_place_link" role="link">Audi</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=bmw" class="car_place_link"  role="link">Bmw</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=jaguar"class="car_place_link"role="link">Jaguar</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=maserati" class="car_place_link"role="link">Maserati</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=all" class="car_place_link" role="link">All type</a>

 </nav>
```

Вот вывод из бд

```
    <?php

    include 'pages/db.php';

    $sql="SELECT * FROM  `car` ORDER BY ,$cars ";

    $querry=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($querry)){

    echo '

    <div class="car_intro_container">

    <div class="car_image_count">

      <img src="images/'.$row['img'].'" class="template_image" alt="template- 
 image">


    </div>

    </div>


    ';

    }

      mysqli_close($connection);



    ?>
```

Из бд  должно быть выборка   логотипов производителей.

Comment: Есть предположения ???

Comment: `$sql="SELECT * FROM  `car` ORDER BY ,$cars ";` - уберите запятую перед `$cars`. Что у вас находится в переменной  `$cars`? Судя из кода запрос. В результате вы делаете запрос в БД и при этом сортируете полученный результат  по столбцу которого не существует в БД

Comment: Есть  столбец  `car`  в котором находятся  основные марки

Comment: Ну так и сортируйте по этому столбцу `$sql = "SELECT * FROM car ORDER BY car ";` - в таком случае вы получите всю информацию с таблицы `car`. Если нужно информацию по конкретной модели исходя из гет параметра то попробуйте так `$sql = $cars . " ORDER BY car ";`

Answer (score 0):

`cars` вместо `car`, и немного изменились команды.

```
$mysqli  = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if ($mysqli ->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
} 

echo "Connected successfully<br>";

$sql="SELECT * FROM  `cars` ORDER BY car_name ";


if ( ($result = $mysqli->query($sql))===false )
{
  printf("Invalid query: %s\nWhole query: %s\n", $mysqli->error, $sql);
  exit();
}

while ($myrow = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo '

    <div class="car_intro_container">

    <div class="car_image_count">

      <img src="images/'.$myrow['img'].'" class="template_image" alt="template- 
 image">


    </div>

    </div>';

    }



    $cars=$_GET['cars'];

    switch($cars){

      case"audi":$cars="SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE car_name=audi";break;
      case"bmw":$cars="SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE car_name=bmw";break;
      case"jaguar":$cars="SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE car_name=jaguar";break;
      case"maserati":$cars="SELECT * FROM `cars` WHERE car_name=maserati";break;
      default:$cars="SELECT * FROM `cars`";

    }

?>




 <nav class="car_navigation" role="navigation">

<a href="index.php?cars=audi" class="car_place_link" role="link">Audi</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=bmw" class="car_place_link"  role="link">Bmw</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=jaguar"class="car_place_link"role="link">Jaguar</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=maserati" class="car_place_link"role="link">Maserati</a>

<a href="index.php?cars=all" class="car_place_link" role="link">All type</a>

 </nav>

 <?php $mysqli->close(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Друзья  я сделал  некоторые  изменения  в  коде  все  стало хорошо работать но  при загрузки сайта появляется такое  оповешение

```
Notice:  Undefined index: car in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\index.php on line 5
```

Проблема в переменном `$car` .Можете подсказать  где ошибка  в коде .
Вот код.

```
<?php

include 'pages/db.php';

  $car=$_GET['car'];

 if(isset($_GET['car'])){



     switch($car){

      case'audi':$car="WHERE `car_name`='audi'";break;
      case'bmw':$car=" WHERE `car_name`='bmw'";break;
      case'jaguar':$car="WHERE `car_name`='jaguar'";break;
      case'maserati':$car="WHERE `car_name`='maserati'";break;

      default:$car=" ORDER BY `cars` `car_name` ASC";

    }

 }


?>
```

Навигационная часть

```
<nav class="car_navigation" role="navigation">
<a href='index.php?car=audi' class="car_link"   role="link">Audi</a>
<a href='index.php?car=bmw' class="car_link"  role="link">Bmw</a>
<a href='index.php?car=jaguar' class="car_link"  role="link">Jaguar</a>
<a href='index.php?car=maserati' class="car_link"    role="link">Maserati</a>
</nav>
```

Вывод из БД

```
<?php

include 'pages/db.php';

 $sql="SELECT * FROM `cars` $car  ";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){

while($myrow=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo '

    <div class="car_intro_container">

    <div class="car_image_count">

      <img src="images/'.$myrow['img'].'" class="template_image" alt="template- 
 image">

</div>

<p>'.$myrow['car_name'].'</p>

    </div>';

    }

}


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```